# Youtube embed not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, youtube, embed

I have this site:

http://www.israelsport.co.il

I'm embedding a YouTube video on one of the articles (look under the strip of commercials).

For some reason the video is not embedded properly on Chrome (Can't click to activate, shows the controls) While it does embed perfectly on Firefox.

The code I'm using for embedding is:

```
<iframe width="315" height="180" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gDUUc-D75SQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Can someone help me solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice to have an example page and the code which you are using here in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ran into the same problem. try:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com...
```

instead of:

```
src="//www.youtube.com...
```